# Apache Spark DataSet API : head(n:Int) vs take(n:Int)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Apache Spark Dataset API has two methods i.e, `head(n:Int)` and `take(n:Int)`.

Dataset.Scala source contains

```
def take(n: Int): Array[T] = head(n)
```

Couldn't find any difference in execution code between these two functions. why do API has two different methods to yield the same result?

Comment: It's just an implementation choice. Nothing much to discuss about that point.

Comment: head returns a `Row` if you don't pass any paramters to it whereas `take` always return an `Array` is the only difference I can think of.

Comment: @eliasah - So, can we take it as redundancy in API?

Comment: Yes. As for my opinion, that the case.

Comment: Also take in case used distributed: Running take requires moving data into the application's driver process, and doing so with a very large n can crash the driver process with OutOfMemoryError

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because, in my view, Apache Spark Dataset API is trying to mimic Pandas DataFrame API which contains `head` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html.

Answer (score 3):

**I have experimented & found that head(n) and take(n) gives exactly same replica output. Both produces output in the form of ROW object only.**

> > > DF.head(2)

[Row(Transaction_date=u'1/2/2009 6:17', Product=u'Product1', Price=u'1200', Payment_Type=u'Mastercard', Name=u'carolina', City=u'Basildon', State=u'England', Country=u'United Kingdom'), Row(Transaction_date=u'1/2/2009 4:53', Product=u'Product2', Price=u'1200', Payment_Type=u'Visa', Name=u'Betina', City=u'Parkville', State=u'MO', Country=u'United States')]

> > > DF.take(2)

[Row(Transaction_date=u'1/2/2009 6:17', Product=u'Product1', Price=u'1200', Payment_Type=u'Mastercard', Name=u'carolina', City=u'Basildon', State=u'England', Country=u'United Kingdom'), Row(Transaction_date=u'1/2/2009 4:53', Product=u'Product2', Price=u'1200', Payment_Type=u'Visa', Name=u'Betina', City=u'Parkville', State=u'MO', Country=u'United States')]

Answer (score 2):

```
  package org.apache.spark.sql
  /* ... */

  def take(n: Int): Array[T] = head(n)
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because spark developers tends to give it a rich API, there also the two methods `where` and `filter` which does exactly the same thing.

Comment: Is that a "rich" API? Your answer is fine, and I don't mean to heckle it. But these choices by Spark violate the simple Python dictum of "[There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)". Not to be too nitpicky... Spark is awesome. Just frustrating to run across this sort of "solved problem" creeping back into our lives.

Comment: @haroun your definition of Rich API is exactly what it should not be.

Comment: @ChrisOdney how's that ? what's a Rich API so ?

Comment: @HarounMohammedi A Rich API offers a lot interaction mechanisms with the underlying service but if the mechanisms offered are high in number because of redundancy it is not exactly a rich API, it is a API design smell. To quote an example from the JAVA SDK, some of the Collection classes offer redundant API because they implement multiple interfaces which have different names for the same functionality. So if the Spark Class is offering 2 different methods which do exactly the same thing, it is not exactly a Rich API but a redundancy in the API. Brevity is a cornerstone of any good API.