# save minimum value from date field in variable

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have an example dataframe like the df.show() below.  I'm running the pyspark code below to get the minimum dateclosed value in df, so that I can then use it to filter df and create new dataframes train_df and eval_df.  My plan is to turn this in to a for loop, so that I step the "minimum date" forward 60 days and create two new train_df and eval_df over and over again (similarly to the step below) and save them in to a list.  I'm wondering if there's a quicker alternative to the "take" step I'm using to get the minimum date.  Like I guess I could use a left join and filter the dataframe but then it gets tricky when I want to add 60 days to the minimum date and repeat.

code:

```
min_dt=df[['dateclosed']].select(min(col('dateclosed'))).take(1)[0][0]

max_dt=date_add(lit(min_dt),60)

train_df=df[(df['dateclosed']>=min_dt)&(df['dateclosed']<=max_dt)]

eval_df=df[(df['dateclosed']>max_dt)&(df['dateclosed']<=date_add(max_dt,30))]
```

example data:

```
df.show()


+----------+---+
|dateclosed|qty|
+----------+---+
|2020-04-23|1.0|
|2019-10-25|1.0|
|2020-04-01|1.0|
|2020-02-14|1.0|
|2019-10-18|1.0|
|2020-01-11|2.0|
|2019-12-28|1.0|
|2020-01-21|1.0|
|2020-01-26|1.0|
|2020-04-09|1.0|
|2019-07-07|2.0|
|2019-08-03|1.0|
|2019-07-23|1.0|
|2020-03-20|1.0|
|2019-12-14|1.0|
|2020-01-25|1.0|
|2020-03-12|1.0|
|2019-09-21|1.0|
|2019-07-13|1.0|
|2019-10-29|1.0|
+----------+---+
```

Comment: df.agg(min(df.dateclosed)).head()[0] - please, try

Comment: @mvasyliv that didn't seem to speed it up.  what's the difference between .take() and .head()

Comment: [Discussion .take() vs .head() : ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45138742/apache-spark-dataset-api-headnint-vs-takenint)